CORDIC algorithm in RISC-V
I'm trying to implement CORDIC algorithm for calculating sine and cosine of specified angle in RISC-V assembly using RARS simulator.
I'm defining format of my fixed-point binary number as Q1.30, so there is one bit for sign, one for integer values and 30 for fractional values.
I'm using this algorithm in rotation mode: from CORDIC ALGORITHM and also this for support: an-introduction-to-the-cordic-algorithm/
I marked certain register purposes:

t0 for storing atan values from lookup table
t1 x_i value from algorithm (this represents cosine value at the end)
t2 y_i value from algorithm (this represents sine value at the end)
t3 z_i value from algorithm (0 for z_i would represent that we rotate exact amount of our desired angle, first it is initialized with desired angle)
t4 number of iterations (31 for this approach, because lookup table is of that size)
t5 value at a certain atan_table position
t6 current num of iteration
s0&s1 - auxiliary registers for shifting

After converting my result using this site: Q-format converter, I don't get correct values for sine and cosine. E.g. for angle = 45 degrees (I convert everything to radians), I'm getting approximately 0,6 for cosine and 0,5 for sine (I should get around 0,7).
This is my code:
.data
    newLine: .asciz "\n"
    iteration: .asciz "\n Number of iteration: \n"
    angle: .asciz "\n Printing angle: \n"
    cosine: .asciz "\n Printing cosine value: \n"
    sine: .asciz "\n Printing sine value: \n"
    a_tan_table: .asciz "\n Printing a_tan_table value: \n"
    sigma_minus: .asciz "\n Sigma minus! \n\n"
    sigma_plus: .asciz "\n Sigma plus! \n\n"

    atan_table:
        .word 0x3243f6a9
        .word 0x1dac6705
        .word 0x0fadbafd
        .word 0x07f56ea7
        .word 0x03feab77
        .word 0x01ffd55c
        .word 0x00fffaab
        .word 0x007fff55
        .word 0x003fffeb
        .word 0x001ffffd
        .word 0x00100000
        .word 0x00080000
        .word 0x00040000
        .word 0x00020000
        .word 0x00010000
        .word 0x00008000
        .word 0x00004000
        .word 0x00002000
        .word 0x00001000
        .word 0x00000800
        .word 0x00000400
        .word 0x00000200
        .word 0x00000100
        .word 0x00000080
        .word 0x00000040
        .word 0x00000020
        .word 0x00000010
        .word 0x00000008
        .word 0x00000004
        .word 0x00000002
        .word 0x00000001

    K:
        .word 0x26DD3B6A
        #.word 0x40000000

    angle_0:
        .word 0x3243f6a9 # 45 degrees

.text
    la t0, atan_table

    # Initializing x
    la t1, K 
    lw t1, 0(t1)

    # Initializing y (sin)
    li t2, 0 

    # Initializing z
    la t3, angle_0 
    lw t3, 0(t3)

    li t6, 0 # current iteration
    li t4, 32 # it is num_of_iterations - 1

loop:
    # Printing angle
    li a7, 4
    la a0, angle
    ecall
    
    # Printing angle value
    li a7, 35
    mv a0, t3
    ecall
    
    # Printing num of iterations
    li a7, 4
    la a0, iteration
    ecall

    # Number of iteration
    li a7, 1
    mv a0, t6
    ecall

    # Printing cosine
    li a7, 4
    la a0, cosine
    ecall

    # Printing cosinus
    li a7, 35
    mv a0, t1
    ecall

    # Printing sine
    li a7, 4
    la a0, sine
    ecall

    # Printing sinus
    li a7, 35
    mv a0, t2
    ecall

    beq t6, t4, end
    bge t3, zero, first_sub_alg # if z[i] >=0, sigma_i = 1
    j later_sub_alg # if z[i] < 0, sigma_i = -1

first_sub_alg:
    lw t5, 0(t0) # loading i-th value from atan_table #first_sub_alg
    addi t0, t0, 4 # going to the next value from atan_table
    
    # Printing a_tan_table value
    li a7, 4
    la a0, a_tan_table
    ecall
    
     # Printing a_tan_table value
    li a7, 34
    mv a0, t5
    ecall
    
    li a7, 4
    la a0, sigma_plus
    ecall   
    
    # x[i+1] = x[i] - 2^(-i)*y[i]
    li s0, 0
    sra s0, t2, t6
    sub t1, t1, s0

    # y[i+1] = y[i] + 2^(-i)*x[i]
    li s1, 0
    sra s1, t1, t6
    add t2, t2, s1

    # z[i+1] = z[i] - atan(2^(-i))
    # lw t5, -4(t0)
    sub t3, t3, t5

    addi t6, t6, 1 # i=i+1
    j loop

later_sub_alg:
    lw t5, 0(t0) # loading i-th value from atan_table #later_sub_alg
    addi t0, t0, 4 # going to the next value from atan_table

    # Printing a_tan_table value
    li a7, 4
    la a0, a_tan_table
    ecall
    
     # Printing a_tan_table value
    li a7, 34
    mv a0, t5
    ecall
    
    li a7, 4
    la a0, sigma_minus
    ecall   
    
    # x[i+1] = x[i] + 2^(-i)*y[i]
    li s0, 0
    sra s0, t2, t6
    add t1, t1, s0

    # y[i+1] = y[i] - 2^(-i)*x[i]
    li s1, 0
    sra s1, t1, t6
    sub t2, t2, s1

    # z[i+1] = z[i] + atan(2^(-i))
    # lw t5, -4(t0)
    add t3, t3, t5

    addi t6, t6, 1 # i=i+1
    j loop

end:
    # Printing newLine
    li a7, 4
    la a0, newLine
    ecall

    li a7, 93
    li a0, 0
    ecall

I traced execution of this program and checked that z_i has correct values. Can somebody help? Thanks

The code does not seem to distinguish between old x, y and new x, y. So the y-update uses the already updated value of x, instead of the old value of x.

@njuffa oh my god, thank you, I didn't realize this was such a stupid mistake, now it's working
